# Faster measure of distance

Tags: java, performance, distance

I'm currently working with a game and I need to send packets from the server to the client to produce certain particle effects on the client, however, clients are only able to render this particles if they are within a radius of 64 cubic units in the game.

In order to avoid sending packets to all the clients I will measure the distance between the client and the point where the particles originate, but the distance will be calculated for each client and should run in less than a game tick (50 ms).

The particles will be played with the player movement, and will be sent to all clients within the distance, so performance is a bit crucial (considering a several amount of players).

The game API provides this formula (no square root) for the distance between two locations:

`square(x1 - x2) + square(y1 - y2) + square(z1 - z2);`

My idea was to create a 'box' of 128 length on each axis using the particle as the center point, the downside of this is that the clients on the corner will not render the particle but will get the packet, wasting a bit of bandwidth.

Question is, measuring the distance using euclidean distance will be faster than simply creating a 'box' around the particles and comparing if the clients are inside of it? Are there any other methods to get a faster distance measurement?

Comment: 0.x ? Don't you mean x/10 ?

Comment: @Charlie it is not a `0` it is an `o`, as in the other objects location.

Comment: Should've said that in the post itself, plus the code you already tried

Comment: Hmm calculating on client side is not an option?

Comment: I removed the context in the distance formula, hope it's a bit more clear, about code, I'm just asking if using the formula of the API would be faster than creating an imaginary box around the particle and checking if clients are inside of it.

@Dima No, the game works only with server-side plugins, so clients can connect with the original game, I can only do this particles server-side unless I want the clients to modify their game.

Comment: Why not write a small test program for that and measure.

Comment: @Dima Well, getting 50 players for a real test doesn't seem too feasible for me, since the particles are played with movement I need a lot of real players to have a real test, otherwise a test by myself wont show if there is a performance issue or not.

Comment: @Konato_K, you don't need 50 players to test which method is faster. A small test will do.

Comment: @Konato_K How dose it matter if you only measure the time it takes for an operation?

Comment: @Jonathan You mean testing the code alone without the game? I guess that's an option, but as far I know trying to benchmark it's a little inaccurate, but I guess you have a point.

Comment: @Konato_K, Do users and particles move, or do users move and particles are stationary?

Comment: I agree with @DimaMaligin that you need to test to find out, but I'd be very surprised if anything more complex was faster the formula that you have.

Comment: @Jonathan Particles are pretty much static, but that doesn't matter too much since the client knows how to produce them, I just need to tell the clients when to.

Comment: @Konato_K Just measure the API formula against your method and see. If it's faster for one calculation then it's definitely more efficient for more than one calculation. Although it's best to measure on N calculations and taking the average for a more accurate result.

Answer (score 2):

A very efficient way to do this, especially with a large number of points, is to use an Oct-tree (a three-dimensional Quad-tree) as a data structure.

See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) for an introduction.

This is a 3-dimensional spatial index, allowing you to quickly retrieve points within a certain three-dimensional (rectangular) range.

If you want to reduce the number of points further, you can use your distance formula to filter down the points you found further; but the number of points should already be so significantly reduced by using the Oct-tree spatial index that this doesn't subtract much from the performance.